# How to get day of month in 20th format in java?

Tags: java, datetime

I need to get the day of month ends with th or st e.g **20th**, **21st**.

Is it possible to achieve it java date time format? Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. This question has been asked multiple times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this first where you are using.

```
if(value <=30){
   getOrdinalFor(value)
}else{
  return "st";
}
```

here is your core logic

```
public static String getOrdinalFor(int value) {
 int tenRemainder = value % 20;

 switch (tenRemainder) {
 case 1:
    return "st";
 case 2:
    return "nd";
 case 3:
    return "rd";
 default:
    return "th";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can do what you want:

```
public class Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + getOrdinalFor(i));
    }
    }

    public static String getOrdinalFor(int value) {
        int tenRemainder = value % 10;
     if (value == 11 || value == 12 || value == 13) {
        return "th";
     }
     switch (tenRemainder) {
     case 1:
        return "st";
     case 2:
        return "nd";
     case 3:
        return "rd";
     default:
        return "th";
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the value is 11, 12 or 13??

Comment: nice one... we need to validate that....

Comment: @EhsanAnjum please give a try again to the updated version and let me know..... :)